# How can I access a column of a line from within a string?

Tags: shell-script, awk, printing, string

I have a file I'm traversing in a `for` loop. I want to do something like...

`for line in file.out; do echo "Some text before $line($2) $line($3)"; done`

Where, for every line I insert the 2nd and 3rd column from that line to the current string. Is there a straightforward way of doing this? Can I access awk from within a string?

Sample input:

```
some.metric.tag_A 100500 1446043920
some.metric.tag_B 100501 1446043921
some.metric.tag_C 100502 1446043922
some.metric.tag_D 100503 1446043923
```

Sample output:

```
Some text before 100500 1446043920
Some text before 100501 1446043921
Some text before 100502 1446043922
Some text before 100503 1446043923
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using awk

awk implicitly loops through lines and separates each line into fields:

```
$ awk '{printf "Some text before %s %s\n",$2,$3}' file.out
Some text before 100500 1446043920
Some text before 100501 1446043921
Some text before 100502 1446043922
Some text before 100503 1446043923
```

If we know that the input file will always only have three columns, then this command can be shortened to (Hat tip: Don Crissti):

```
$ awk '{$1="Some text before"} 1' file.out
```

#### Using shell

Lines can be broken into fields using the shell's `read` statement:

```
$ while read a b c d; do echo "Some text before $b $c" ; done <file.out
Some text before 100500 1446043920
Some text before 100501 1446043921
Some text before 100502 1446043922
Some text before 100503 1446043923
```

Comment: Very nice. I much prefer the `awk` version you posted.

Comment: @MrDuk I do also.  This is just the type of thing that awk was designed for.

Comment: @don_crissti Very nice!  I added that version to the answer.